# VS code doesn't recognize arduino specific syntax

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, arduino, arduino-ide

I've installed C++ and Arduino extensions for my VS code, and most of it seem to work (it tries to connect to a board, for example), but the language recognition and IntelliSense keep marking Arduino keywords as errors and doesn't complete anything that isn't pure C++. what am I doing wrong?
[image]

Edit: I've figured out where things go wrong. the C++ configuration is set to Win32, but the Arduino config does not exist. it isn't in the json either. seems like the arduino extension failed to modify the c_cpp_properties.json, but still I can't fix it because i don't know what is supposed to be the content of the json.

Comment: Those are not keywords, but functions (`pinMode()`, `digitalWrite`) or macros (`OUTPUT`, `HIGH`).

Comment: You can try `#include <Arduino.h>`

Comment: @KIIV i get the error cannot open source file "Arduino.h". but thats the only error.
I've narrowed down the problem to the C++ config manu, its set to Win32 and there's no Arduino option available. couldn't find the arduino section in the json either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution that finally worked for me was to open an example (the arduino package comes with examples). then i chose a board and verified the code, the json file called c_cpp_properties, that up until now only had the configuration for Win32, was modified to contain the configs needed for arduino. its been e journey.